What is the difference between "Us girls gotta stick together" and "We girls gotta stick together"?
I am looking into the difference between the "we" and "us" pronouns, and have found some very useful information here.
In the context of emphasizing a particular group, you can put "we" or "us" before a noun. So "Us girls gotta stick together," and "We girls gotta stick together," are valid sentences.
Even so, I would like know if there is a difference between "Us girls gotta stick together," and "We girls gotta stick together." If there is, what might that be?

A similar question was asked on English Language Learners and the answer said there was no difference other than "us" being more informal or possibly dialectal. (There's another question here on a threat to us people but that's about the object rather than the subject.)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

As CGEL notes (p. 459), in the subject of a finite clause "we find variation with the personal determinative we, with nominative we being the norm but very colloquial and dialectal varieties having accusative us." Your example sentences use we/us as personal determinatives, in their terminology, so that principle applies, with  "We girls gotta stick together" being the norm and "Us girls gotta stick together" being found in colloquial speech or certain nonstandard dialects.

I would dispute that "We girls gotta stick together" is the "norm".  "We girls" is the normal "proper, correct" form of the nominative but you will rarely find "we girls" in the company of "gotta stick together".  There's a register clash. "Us girls, us guys" is not at all uncommon in the speech of people in the US who haven't been to college.  I have heard it all my life in Delaware County Pennsylvania, outside of Philadelphia.  But I don't think it's isolated to this region of the country.

@TimR I'm a bit perplexed. If "gotta stick together" is common across education levels, and if it's more likely to be preceded by "Us girls" than "We girls," would it not follow that "Us girls" is also common across education levels?

I wouldn't agree that "gotta stick together" is "common acoss educational levels".  gotta  would be replaced with "must" by some speakers.  And not all educational levels or registers would use the phrase "stick together".

@TimR I find that frankly absurd; it's pretty obvious that, in informal registers (and sometimes even in formal contexts), even the most educated of people use gotta without a preceding have (in speech, of course, not in writing). I can dig up plenty of examples if you'd like.

It's absurd that you wouldn't consider "gotta stick together" as a form of "code-switching".  "Frankly absurd" is not something that would be used by Mr Green in the novel I quote from in my answer, BTW.

@TimR As for  "gotta," "We gotta" is used by such uneducated people as many lecturers at Stanford, the CEO of LinkedIn, James Comey, and Hillary Clinton.

@alphabet You have commited a first-degree fallacy: bad transcription rules used by speech-to-text software do not mean that those speakers actually said one word not two. When you're trained only on eye-dialect instead of curated text, mistakes galore will be made by mindless AI.  It is not possible to analyze eye-dialect txtspx abrv8shnz as individual lexemes in the language. It is a disservice to translate educated speakers' speech into uneducated eye-dialect like dint, shouldna, aincha, wanna, gonna. Spell those out or you insult the speakers' educations.

@alphabet You cannot attribute any reasonable word class to iDialex like gonna, wanna because the moment you write those as single words there is no traditional part of speech that can be used for them. They appear to take bare infinitive clauses yet are not modals nor causatives etc. They undergo no syntactic transformations. We do not rewrite weak forms of all the function words of English into belittling eye dialect without this saying something about the speaker into whose mouths you would place such things. Mark Twain did this deliberately but AIs are mindless morons that know nothing.

@tchrist This is too long for a comments section, but: nowhere am I citing YouTube's closed captions or endorsing their accuracy or saying that they present the speaker in the best possible light. My point is that those speakers are saying /wiˈɡɔɾ.ə/, without any trace of the -'ve there. Whether they think of those sounds as representing "we gotta" or "we've got to" I do not claim to know. But what's most important is that there's no trace of the word have in their pronunciations--that's the weird part, and it isn't applicable to forms like wanna (which CGEL argues is just a verb, btw).

@alphabet Just-a-verbs would have 3s and other inflections, but these do not:  He ❌wannas leave, He’s ❌wannaing leave, He ❌wannaed leave. And if they're modals, they have an inversion problem: Wanna ❌he leave?  All that and more is why these cannot be "just verbs" in any regular sense of that term. They cannot be analyzed in any other way if not spelt out in full, at which point yes, they are simply verbs. But not written in eye-dialect, because they stop behaving like verbs unless you go creating a brand new bespoke subclass just for them alone, which is neither productive nor predictive.

@alphabet I believe that Ya gotta wanna is a common illustration of have-deletion.

People might see the differences between the two versions differently depending on their age and whether they grew up  where most people in the community said "us guys, us girls" or "we guys, we girls".
"us girls, us guys"  as subject in the sentence is exactly the sort of "common, vulgar" speech that was focused on in the "learn English grammar at home" books that were popular in the US in the first half of the 20th century, aimed at people who didn't go to school beyond high school and who were working with more educated people, like clerical staff at law firms and insurance companies.
The phrase "gotta stick together" is a colloquialism and it is something of a register clash to hear it yoked with the "correct" "We girls".
Compare:  "It's me"  vs "It is I".
Here's a bit of dialog from a 1922 novel entitled The Secret Toll by Paul and Mabel Thorne, in a chapter called "Friends of the Poor":

"I'll tell you, Mister," said Green. "I've been followin' this here case right from the start. I've got some theories, too, that I ain't been tellin' to nobody. I've just been itchin' to get busy on it, but you know us guys have to make a livin' —we can't work on a case for nothin'."

As you can see, "us guys" hangs out in the company of "ain't" and "this here" and the dropping of  -g- from words ending in -ing, which are presented as telltale language traits of the unpolished.
